# Dynamically read record of XML file in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have records in XML format. I have 10 different xml records. Now I want php function to read XML record dynamically.

I have created method but it works for single type of xml. My code is :

```
function readXMLDoc($xml_file){
    $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
    $res = $xmlDoc->load('uploads/xml_records/'.$xml_file);

    if (!$res) {
        echo("Failed to parse XML\n");
        return false;
    }

    $events = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName("photoSet");
    $data= array();
    foreach($events as $key=>$event):       
         $dates = $event->getElementsByTagName("desc");
         $data[$key]['desc'] = $dates->item(0)->nodeValue;

         $venues = $event->getElementsByTagName("set");
         $data[$key]['set'] = $venues->item(0)->nodeValue;

         $names = $event->getElementsByTagName("number");
         $data[$key]['number'] = $names->item(0)->nodeValue;

         $names = $event->getElementsByTagName("thumb");
         $data[$key]['thumb'] = $names->item(0)->nodeValue;
    endforeach;  
    return $data;
}
```

I want dynamically, get node name and value.

Comment: Maybe try using some XML Library for PHP?(http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

Comment: Or PHP's native DOMDocument http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I know of is with the built-in [SimpleXML class](https://www.php.net/simplexml_load_file).

You can iterate through the XML DOM more-or-less like an array.  If you would like further assistance, please post the code you've tried so far.